# single vs double square brackets in python

Tags: python, list, brackets

I get different results when I print from a list that have single ([) vs double ([[) brackets. For example, the output with double brackets is different than with single bracket when using the same python code.

```
my_movies = [['How I Met your Mother', 'Friends', 'sillicon valley','The Wire','breakin bad',
'Family Guy','Game of Throne','South park', 'Rick and Morty']]

my_movies = ['How I Met your Mother', 'Friends', 'sillicon valley','The Wire','breakin bad',
'Family Guy','Game of Throne','South park', 'Rick and Morty']

for movies in my_movies: 
    for movie in movies:
        char_num=len(movie)
        print (movie)
```

Question:
How does the single vs double bracket changes the list?

Comment: It's not double square brackets. It's just a list whose elements are also lists, so they have square brackets around their parts.

Comment: Single bracket is used for lists. If you have double brackets, it means you have a list of list l.

Comment: Bracket defines list. Double brackets defines list with single element which is list.

Comment: As stated above, double brackets it just means that you have a list inside a list. The first list has just one element: the list with your movies, and the list inside it is the list of movies. Also, it's important to note that strings, as they are iterables, work pretty much as a list of characters

Comment: BTW, those are TV shows, not movies. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list inside a list is called a nested list. In the following list `my_movies_1`, you have length 1 for `my_movies_1` and the length of the inner list is 9. This inner list is accessed using `my_movies_1[0]`.

```
my_movies_1 = [['How I Met your Mother', 'Friends', 'sillicon valley','The Wire','breakin bad', 'Family Guy','Game of Throne','South park', 'Rick and Morty']]
```

On the other hand, the following list is **not** a nested list and has a length of 9

```
my_movies_2 = ['How I Met your Mother', 'Friends', 'sillicon valley','The Wire','breakin bad','Family Guy','Game of Throne','South park', 'Rick and Morty']
```

**How are they related**:

Here `my_movies_1[0]` would give you `my_movies_2`

Answer (score 0):

The single bracket will output a Pandas Series, while a double bracket will output a Pandas DataFrame. Square brackets can also be used to access observations (rows) from a DataFrame.

[Look at this article, which may help if you need to](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics#:%7E:text=The%20single%20bracket%20will%20output,will%20output%20a%20Pandas%20DataFrame.&text=Square%20brackets%20can%20also%20be,(rows)%20from%20a%20DataFrame.)